# Autocomplete not working on Mma9 on Linux

Tags: front-end, linux, autocomplete

I started using Mathematica 9 on Ubuntu 12.10 and, sometimes, autocomplete doesn't work. The suggestions window shows up for just a fraction of second, and quickly disappears.

Do you have any idea on how I can sold this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works for me on Fedora 18; can you make the "sometimes" more precise ? Is it random ?

Comment: Yep, it really is random (though most of the times it just disappears very quickly). It is very rare for me to be able to use the autocomplete, and after working with it on Windows, it becomes really annoying not being able to use it.

Comment: @Sosi Can you check that `"ReleaseID" /. SystemInformation["FrontEnd"]` gives "9.0.1.0 (4092720, 4092443)"?  If not, re-download Mathematica from the user portal and re-install it (or bug your sysadmin ...)

Comment: It gives ""9.0.1.0 (4055667, 4055631)". Seems like I need to redownload it again.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is fixed in the newest version of Mathematica 9.0.1 (at least for me). Notice: Wolfram published several versions with the name "9.0.1" for Linux and only the current one (md5 sum 7fcbc4d1488757b10ef07740ac30a580) fixed this bug.

Comment: Indeed, reinstalling it with a newer version fixes this problem!